# derivaton of lenz law according to conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

How can we derive Lenz's law according to the law of conservation of energy?

Answer with diagram would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine the north pole of a magnet approaching a coil in series with a resistor.

[image]

An emf is induced and because there is a complete electrical circuit an induced current flows in the coil and resistor.

To oppose the motion of the magnet the induced current (red) has to produce a magnetic field (blue) as shown in the diagram.

That means that work has to be done to move the magnet closer.
In this case that work ends up as heat in the coils and resistor due to the induced current passing through them.
The work done pushing the magnet produces electrical energy which in turn produces heat.

If the induced current was in the opposite direction then the induced magnetic field direction would be reversed and there would be a force of attraction between the magnet and the induced magnetic field.
So the magnet would move faster gaining kinetic energy whilst at the same time there would be a heating effect in the coil and the resistor due to the induced current.
So there are two types of energy being produced (heat and kinetic) spontaneously which contravenes the law of conservation of energy.

If the resistor had not been present then there would still have been an induced emf but no induced current, no induced magnetic field and so no opposition to the movement of the magnet.
This does not contravene the law of conservation of energy because there is no heat produced in the this case and so no work done pushing the magnet into the coil results in no energy output from the coil.